# rsync + failed on error with Bad file descriptor

Tags: linux, rsync, redhat-enterprise-linux, kernel, file-descriptors

usually we not have this issue so its very rare!

but today we got the following error when we are using `rsync` to copy files . when files - `pkg_gh` are with 1-3G size

the error is like this

```
Warning: Permanently added '130.33.90.18' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
rsync: read errors mapping "/target/home_l/repo/pkg_gh": Bad file descriptor (9)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1178) [sender=3.1.2]
```

what is the meaning when we get -  `Bad file descriptor` , when using `rsync`?

is it something that we can avoid?

for example kernel settings? or `rsync` rpm upgrade? etc ?

the cmd is like this

```
sshpass XXXXXX /usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --archive --rsh=/usr/bin/ssh -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null  --out-format=.....  /target/home_l/repo/pkg_gh root:$target_server:/tmp/local_folder
```

and the `rsync` is working between two rhel server from local server to target server , when server are connected VIA Cisco switch

Comment: Is `/target/home_l/repo/pgk_gh` on a network share (NFS or SMB/CIFS, for example)?

Comment: its NFS network filesystem

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates a *read* error, not a write error

```
rsync: read errors mapping "/target/home_l/repo/pkg_gh": Bad file descriptor (9)
```

You confirmed in a comment that your source file is on an NFS filesystem, and it's here that the read write occurred. Your NFS file system momentarily failed to deliver part of the file that `rsync` was copying.

Comment: any comment hot to avoid this issue ?

Comment: Rerun the `rsync` with the `--partial` flag to keep partially transferred files. If it fails again talk to your sysadmins about the repeated NFS failure